# Catch URL after click with Cypress (window.location changes)

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I would like to know how to capture and read the URL after a click event on an `<a>` link.

On the onClick event our javascript does some string manipulation of the  actual `href` of the clicked link and then a `window.location.href = myNewReplacebleURL` is done on the fly. The original `href` is not necessarily the location you get to after the onClick.

Here is how I started:

```js
describe("Twitter", function() {

  it("Should assert that via value is set correctly in JS", function() {

    cy.server();
    cy.visit(Cypress.config("appUrl") + "/probes/sha/sha-via.html");
    cy.get("#v_test ul.share li a")
      .click();

  });

});
```

**EDIT**: What I would like is to catch the URL located at the "Page Load" step.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue somehow?

Comment: No, I wonder if this is even possible

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to use [cy.on](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#App-Events) to perform your [assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions) inside the *`url:changed`* event callback:

```js
cy.on("url:changed", (newUrl) => {
  expect(newUrl).to.contain("?magic=true")
})
```

Comment: I had to use this approach to catch query params changes, but I don't get it. Usually, Cypress philosophy is to retry until your assertion work, so `cy.url().should("match", "?foo=bar")` would be expected to wait for the url to match "foo=bar". It is not the case, I have to listen to  `url:changed` as you described to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the[`cy.location()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location.html) command, example:

```
cy.get("#v_test ul.share li a")
      .click();
cy.location('href').should('eq', 'newUrl');
```

Also, as an alias to the `cy.location('href')` command you could use [`cy.url()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html).

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in my updated image, I would like to stop at the page load step. The generated URL (which does not exist as newURL inside Cypress) can sometimes redirect multiple times.

Comment: try to add cy.location('pathname') instead cy.location('href').

Comment: This no longer works with the latest version of cypress (6.0.1 as of today)